# Tomcat 8 HTTPS connection not working on AWS EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, ssl, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to set up a HTTPS connection in my server where I have tomcat deployed.

I've tried [this](https://devtidbits.com/2015/05/09/create-self-signed-certificates-for-https-with-apache-tomcat/) and [this](https://hutter.io/2016/02/09/java-create-self-signed-ssl-certificates-for-tomcat/) as well as the official step guide from Tomcat, but I keep getting an empty response when trying to connect to https://myec2.com:8443 (the port is open, I checked that already)

My server.xml connector looks like this:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="/path/to/my/keystore.pfx"
    keystorePass="mypassword"
    keystoreType="PKCS12"/>
```

Just in case here is the HTTP connector:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    URIEnconding="UTF-8"/>
```

Is there something I forgot to do? Why is this not working? I've done this before and never had any trouble like this!

Comment: Is this a regular ec2 or do you use elastic beanstalk? Do you use a loadbalancer?

Comment: The path for the keystore could be the issue, where did you place it? http://techtracer.com/2007/09/12/setting-up-ssl-on-tomcat-in-3-easy-steps/

Comment: I placed it in the last tutorial's suggestion, `/etc/ssl/tomcat/keystore.pfx` @drolmal

Comment: Just a regular free tier ec2 @kkflf

Comment: Does Tomcat have access to that location, and can it be be opened with the password you configured ?

Comment: @drolmal should have, I tried the locations from all tutorials, including the lat one you linked, and also in /home/ubuntu/keystore but no way it will work apparently

Comment: With amazon it can be either too much or too little permission, you could try chmod 400 and chmod 775 and figure out if it changes. also if you are reaching Tomcat at all, it should be writing to the log. If you start it command line you will get the messages in standard output as well. This too sounds interesting, apparently you need ports 80 and 443 open as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799947/install-ssl-on-ec2-tomcat-server

Comment: @drolmal It's still not working, seems like HTTPS is unreachable, it doesn't appear in the logs, what should I do?

Comment: Is the server listening on port 8443? Do a netstat to check...

Comment: It's listening, same stats as port 8080

Comment: Did you open port `8443` in the security group assigned to the EC2 instance?

Comment: @MarkB Yes, I said so in the question as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the problem after much investigation...

The problem was that the "alias" of the keystore has to be "tomcat". Apparently, the option `keyAlias="myAlias"`in server.xml did not work.

Thanks for the help identifying it!

Answer (score 2):

I killed seveeral hours on this. And finally found that slashes and backslashes matters.
This works:

```
keystoreFile="C:\Users\Sapfil\.keystore"
```

This not works:

```
keystoreFile="C:/Users/Sapfil/.keystore"
```

(win 7 - 64x | tomcat 8)

Comment: This might not be relevant, as the poster indicated they were running on EC2, which probably, although not certainly, means a linux based system.