# How to properly install a SSL for tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, amazon-ec2, hosting

I am in need of having step by step information about installing a wildcard SSL in tomcat server. I tried suggestions in internet, even contacted the SSL provider but all are messing around, I believe my situation is complex. Check below for my setup.

1. The domain is purchased from www.inmotionhosting.com
2. The server is an Amazon EC2. I have installed Tomcat there (No Apache)
3. The SSL is purchased from Comodo. They sent me 2 files, "STAR_xxx_com.crt" and "STAR_xxx_com.ca-bundle". This is a wildcard SSL

Now, this is all I have. Can someone please provide the step by step instruction about what need to be done?

Comment: Post the Tomcat config that you've tried that did not work.

Comment: Come on, PG. You're on your way to 7K, so you should know that asking for "step by step" anything is a recipe for "too broad" here. What do you mean your provider is "messing around"? What have you found in your substantive research to resolve this?

Comment: @halfer: Actually, they are asking me to generate a CSR, I don't know where it should be generated. Then I just found out that it was generated in my domain provider "inmotionhosting.com". It was done by another person and I was informed that no private key was received. Then I contacted comodo again. Now I am adviced to installed the certificate in "inmotionhosting.com" , export it in PFX format and import to other servers. Totally confused. Also the certificate means the .crt file???

Answer (score 1):

I will try to help because I have been in the same situation where everything is very confusing and you do not know where to go.  First of all, I think Kaushal Kumar Panday answer is correct, I will just try to elaborate a bit more.

1. To make Tomcat work with your certificate, you normally create a keystore (JKS, Java KeyStore). The keystore will contain your certificate (public) and your key (private), which should have been provided. I will get to this point later.
2. To configure Tomcat to use the JKS you edit the `server.xml` file (normally under `tomcat_dir/conf/`) and add something like this:

   ```
       <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                  SSLEnabled="true"
                  maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                  sslProtocol="TLS"
                  keystoreFile="path/mykeystore.jks"
                  keystorePass="123456"
                  keystoreType="JKS"
                  keyAlias="tomcat"
       />
   ```

   This is an example, basically Tomcat configuration... You might want to change the port to `443` and some other details.
3. Now, the only step remaining is how you get to create the .jks file. You will need to use a tool called `keytool` which is in a Java JDK under the `/bin/` dir. I believe the process is the following:

   ```
   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file STAR_xxx_com.ca-bundle -keystore mykeystore.jks

   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias tomcat -file STAR_xxx_com.crt -keystore mykeystore.jks
   ```

(I think I remember the import commands will create the JKS for you but otherwise check for the command that creates it for you)

Answer (score 0):

You would need the **.pfx/.p12** file to add SSL support. You need to run the **certificate export** operation from the device where the **CSR** was generated. Once you have this you can refer this thread: [Install SSL on EC2 Tomcat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799947/install-ssl-on-ec2-tomcat-server)

Comment: "...operation from the device" - You mean from the domain provider?